# Ergodicity question

Tags: limits, ergodic-theory

Let $T$ be ergodic on $(X,\mu)$.

If $f_1,f_2\in L^1(X,\mu)$ and $\int f_2 d\mu\neq 0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_1(T^ix)}{\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f_2(T^ix)}=\frac{\int_X f_1}{\int_X f_2}$?

How to prove this or where can I read the proof?

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Use the [Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BirkhoffsErgodicTheorem.html) to show (1/n) LHS numerator = RHS numerator. Then do the same with the denominator.

Comment: This is called ratio ergodic theorem and you can easily search online and find a proof. If the space is probability measure space then as rpa's comment it is a corollary of Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem. In general it is a little bit more technical.